# Odoo: how to find a view of a modal window in odoo calendar and translate label of name field?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

i want to translate this field. A window appears when you click on calendar and after entering meeting subject it create a new meeting.

[image: entering window]

I`m trying to find it in views.
I Changed field name in models:

```
name = fields.Char(string='Тема зустрічі', required=True)
```

also i add a translation in .po file (it has been earlier)

`#. module: calendar
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:calendar.field_calendar_event__name
msgid "Meeting Subject"
msgstr "Тема зустрічі"`

after rebuilding odoo and updating module it didn`t change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a pop up window launched from calendar_quick_create.js https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/calendar/calendar_quick_create.js#L98 file. So you need to override that function.

What you did, will change in from view and tree view.